# Random query strings load no result found page on calling component through react-roter-config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I am trying to load the products page. I have some query params based on that I want to do some business logic like ***/productsPage?pg=2***. Unfortunately, the URL of such type matches with **App and NoFoundPage**. The expected result should be **App and ProductsListPage**.

routes.js

```
import { RouteConfig } from 'react-router-config';

import App from './App';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import ProductsListPage from './ProductsListPage';

export default [
  {
    ...App,
    routes: [
      {
        component: HomePage,
        path: '/',
        exact: true
      },
      {
        component: UploaderPage,
        path: '/uploader'
      },
      {
        component: ProductsListPage,
        path: '/productsList'
      },
      {
        component: NotFoundPage
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
import Routes from './routes';
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
console.log(matchRoutes(Routes, req.url));
```

**matchRoutes** logs App and No Found Page when using /productsList?pg=2.

*Note: pg=2 is not fixed, we can add as many query params as want. Like /productsList?pg=2&sort=desc*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use req.path instead.

```
console.log(matchRoutes(Routes, req.path));
```